# Data Migration(MySQL(instance in AWS) --> Snowflake)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a requirement where we need to migrate MySQL data which is running on AWS-RDS services to Snowflake. Any pointers/docs/references which can guide us would help.

1. The idea is to create a "data lake" in Snowflake.
2. MySQL instance running on AWS needs to be migrated to Snowflake-data lake.
3. The data needs to be migrated as "semi-structured" data.

Regards,
Somen Swain

Comment: This is far too broad a question to be answered here. I would suggest you either ask a specific, focussed, question here or employ someone who knows what they are doing to architect your solution for you

Comment: As Nick commented it is very broad and generalized question but  there were couple of question were asked in same lines and that give intro about architecting and designing into snowflake from Mysql  and below link  could give some start notes  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64426826/how-to-get-data-from-a-mysql-database-to-snowflake

Comment: Thanks Nick & Anand for the responses. I do understand that it is kind of a Data Migration subject which I am trying to open up. But to be precise  if I can get a direction Point 1 --> Since MySQL instance is in cloud is there any "tool"  available to migrate the data to Snowflake.

Comment: “Is there any tool available to migrate data to Snowflake”? Yes, hundreds. Just google “ETL tools”